# NLog: Remove logging rule by name if it was added without name by LoggingConfiguration.AddRule()?

Tags: c#, nlog

I am new to NLog, but I think I have got a good understand of how it works in the last hours.

After digging deeper into NLog API, several questions about Logging Rules come up. One of them is:
**How can I remove a rule by name (using `LoggingConfiguration.RemoveRuleByName()`) that I have added programmatically by `LoggingConfiguration.AddRule()` before?**

- `LoggingConfiguration.AddRule()` does not provide an argument to set the `LoggingRule.RuleName`.
- `LoggingConfiguration.AddRule()` does not take a `LoggingRule` object.
- I don't want to check every rule in the `LoggingConfiguration.LoggingRules` collection, because this would mean checking them by content, because I cannot set a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing the question, I found the solution, which I want to share here.

The `LoggingConfiguration.LoggingRules` collection is a `IList<LoggingRule>` and thus supports `Add()`, `Clear()`, etc.
Therefore it is possible to add `LoggingRule` objects directly into this list. The `LoggingRule` object can be removed again by `IList<>.Remove()`, and, if it has a name, by `LoggingConfiguration.Remove()`.

Example for adding named rule:

```
var loggingRule1 = new NLog.Config.LoggingRule ();
loggingRule1.RuleName = nameof (loggingRule1); // RuleName can also be set in constructor.
loggingRule1.LoggerNamePattern = "*";
loggingRule1.SetLoggingLevels (NLog.LogLevel.Info, NLog.LogLevel.Error);
loggingRule1.Targets.Add (consoleTarget);
loggingConfiguration.LoggingRules.Add (loggingRule1);

var loggingRule2 = new NLog.Config.LoggingRule ("*", NLog.LogLevel.Trace, NLog.LogLevel.Trace, consoleTarget) { RuleName = "loggingRule2" };
loggingConfiguration.LoggingRules.Add (loggingRule2);

logFactory.ReconfigExistingLoggers ();
// or, if config was not yet set to logFactory: logFactory.Configuration = loggingConfiguration;
```

Example for removing named rule:

```
loggingConfiguration.RemoveRuleByName (nameof (loggingRule1));
logFactory.ReconfigExistingLoggers ();
```

IMHO the API is poorly documented. I will suggest some more comprehensive descriptions.

Comment: The NLog Wiki is open for editing, and you are also wellcome to create pull-request to improve XML-docs. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog